# Undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble solving this problem.  I keep getting the same error: 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):

Here is my likes controller:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
  @like = Like.new
end

  def create
    @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
    # @like = Like.new
    # @like.user = current_user
    # @like.bookmark = @bookmark
    @like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)

    if @like.save
      flash[:notice] = "Bookmark was Liked!"
      redirect_to @bookmark
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to Like Bookmark"
      redirect_to @bookmark
    end
  end

  def destroy
    #@bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
    @like = @bookmark.likes.find(params[:id])

    if @like.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Bookmark was Un-liked."
      redirect_to @bookmark
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error Un-liking bookmark."
      redirect_to @bookmark
    end
  end

end
```

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :topics
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

  def liked(bookmark)
    likes.where(bookmark: bookmark.id).first
  end
end
```

My likes partial:

```
 <div>
  <% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
    <%= link_to [@topic, bookmark, like], class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"> </i>&nbsp; Unlike
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to [@topic, bookmark, Like.new], class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"> </i>&nbsp; Like
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Let me know if I need to show anything else, I appreciate any help

Comment: which action gave you the error? which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: The error is pointing to: `<div>
    <% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
      <%= link_to [@topic, bookmark, like], class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"> </i>&nbsp; Unlike
        <% end %>`

Comment: Specifically to the line ```<% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>```

Comment: In my rails console, if I pull up a Bookmark, it looks like this: `=> #<Bookmark id: 1, url: "http://localhost:3000/topics/11/bookmarks/new", topi
c_id: 11, created_at: "2015-02-17 19:28:17", updated_at: "2015-02-17 19:28:17",
user_id: 1, bookmark_id: nil>
2.0.0-p481 :003 >`    So there is a bookmark id at the beginning, but it is still showing nil for the bookmark_id?

Comment: try changing your `liked` function in `users.rb` to `Like.where(bookmark: bookmark.id).first`

Comment: I changed it, but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: Jenny, could you please try my solution ?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed, I am not seeing your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you are calling the partial try this :

```
<% @bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %> 
  <%= render partial: 'likes/like', locals: {bookmark: bookmark} %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am calling it from my bookmark partial which displays all the bookmarks: `<div class="media-body">
      
    <p><%= link_to "{@bookmark.url}" %></p>
   
      <small><%= link_to "Delete", [@topic, bookmark], method: :delete %></small>
      <%= render partial: 'likes/like', locals: {bookmark: @bookmark} %>
`

Comment: Now, could you add <%= raise bookmark.inspect %> in top of your partial and paste the response here? Want to know if it is getting bookmark.

Comment: I put that in my likes partial. Here is the error: `ActionView::Template::Error (nil):
    1: <%= raise bookmark.inspect %>
    2: <div>
    3:   <% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
    4:     <%= link_to [@topic, bookmark, like], class: 'btn btn-danger', method
: :delete do %>
  app/views/likes/_like.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_likes__like_html_erb___9154224
46_106013160'
  app/views/bookmarks/_bookmark.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_bookmarks__bookmark_ht
ml_erb___33832363_105997840'
  app/views/topics/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_topics_show_html_erb__1179814
84_105692840'`

Comment: Is that where you wanted me to use the <%= raise bookmark.inspect %> ?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you paste the template in your problem as well, and which route you are trying to access?

Comment: I have the likes partial pasted in the original question, do you want me to paste in the bookmark partial?

Comment: So you are using nested partial that is calling likes partial from bookmark partial ? And from where you are calling the bookmark partial ?

Comment: I get the same error if I call the partial from the bookmarks partial, or if I call it from the Topics_show view

Comment: in Topics#show add @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id]) and then call likes partial using my solution, if nothing happen, use the raise and let us know the response.

Comment: This is my `show` method in my `Topics Controller`  `def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
     @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id]) 
    @bookmarks = @topic.bookmarks
  end`  I now get an error that says `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TopicsController#show` `Couldn't find Bookmark without an ID`

Comment: great... remove my line from there and add this in your Topics#show view 
<% @bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
<%= render partial: 'partial', locals: {bookmark: bookmark} %>
<% end %>

Comment: Where should I be pointing the partial to? `render partial: 'likes'`?

Comment: raise @bookmarks.inspect in Topics#show action and let me know what it says, if it find bookmarks of that topic

Comment: I'm not showing any error with the inspect, however now my bookmarks aren't working properly.  I am not getting any errors on the likes anymore, but something isn't displaying my bookmark partial correctly

Comment: Are you sure about your association? What is the output of Topic.last.bookmarks in your console ?

Comment: Ok, I seem to be making some progress, I have the bookmarks partial working, however, when I redirect_to the bookmark through the likes controller, that is not working anymore.

Comment: From which action you are redirecting to which action ? You are progressing, that is great :)

Comment: Likes Controller: `def create
    @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
    @like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)

    if @like.save
      flash[:notice] = "Bookmark was Liked!"
      redirect_to @bookmark
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to Like Bookmark"
      redirect_to @bookmark
    end
  end`

Comment: I can't get the redirect route right. My routes are nested, so I tried `topic_bookmark_path(@bookmark)` but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

In your likes partial, you have:

```
<% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
```

That `=` should be a `==`. With a single equals, you're checking whether the like variable is assigned a truthy value, based on `current_user.liked(bookmark)`. You want a double equals to test equality.

*UPDATE*
If you really mean to both assign and compare, split it into two lines so it looks like it's intentional. It's a microexample of the "Command / Query Separation Principle."

```
<% like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
<% if like %>
```

(Sorry this probably doesn't relate directly to your question, but it was very distracting to see.)

Comment: Changing it to `==` gave me this error: `undefined local variable or method `like' for #<#<Class:0xb0e1860>:0xb8bd958>`

Comment: She is not comparing, she is assigning to use later, I guess!